# video.captureStream not supported chrome 54

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, webrtc, video-capture

When i try to run example code from: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/capture/video-pc/

on Google chrome Version 54.0.2840.90 (64-bit) on Linux Mint, it's not working. Firefox works fine.

What's the problem?

Comment: web console in Chrome 54 says `0.502:  captureStream() not supported`

Comment: Yeah... But whys that?

Comment: That seems like a complaint, not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the [same issue](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/issues/827) and it seems like you have to enable "Experimental Web Platform features" in Chrome in order for the demo to work.

1. Go to chrome://flags
2. search for "Experimental Web Platform features"
3. Enable and relaunch.

Unfortunately it still doesn't work properly, at least when loading the page initially. If I drag the player location though, it seems to work.

Comment: It works with a flag. But i want it to work for generat public. I will use canvas.captureStream together with audio API and make a medaiStream from that.